# AWS S3 Storing Videos Whitepapers etc should allow content search on keywords dates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

We are using Amazon S3 to store organization objects such as Videos, whitepapers, Knowledge Docs etc.
We are also exposing a web interface to search and access the required artifacts.

Initial understanding was that S3 would be able to provide APIs/SDK to facilitate search like based on name, creationdate, etc.

But, as per read-ups on AWS S3 is intended to be a object storage and such doesn't expose any APIs for search. Also, there are options like S3 select but seems they are not cost-effective and not intended to be a support for meta data and index search.

What is the best practice to achieve this. I am sure many organizations must be maintaining their assets in S3 and providing search interface of some sort for their users.

Please provide some insights.

thanks

Comment: store metadata in dynamodb and put it to elasticsearch to make it searchable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search via the console, I would recommend using Resource Groups -> Tag Editors.

If you want to search programatically, you can consider storing the metadata in another s3 bucket and query the data via Athena. Another approach would be to store the data in DDB and query on that table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. S3 does allow you to access meta data through API here is the link i got from support team of aws -

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/issues/926#issuecomment-572242282

though it looks ideal solution would be to move indexing to some other system(indexing) such as elastic/solr/dynamo db as S3 is n't intended to provide meta search capabilities.